# Connect SQL Deployed Database over the Internet

Tags: c#, sql-server

Can anyone tell me how to connect SQL Server database over the internet which is located at one of the Web hosting services like GoDaddy.

Language is **C#**
Sql Server 2005

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the godaddy help pages?
http://help.godaddy.com/article/689

Specifically:

> NOTE: You can find your server name,
>   database name, user ID, and password
>   in the SQL Server section of your
>   Hosting Control Center. These
>   connection string values map to host
>   name, database name, user name, and
>   password, respectively. The user name
>   and password values are those
>   specified during SQL database (not
>   hosting account) creation.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to know the ip address of the sql server to connect to and the authentication details for that server. Use a connection string like the following.

"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=some_ipaddress;UID=some_user_name;PWD=_some_password;DATABASE=some_database_name"

Answer (score 1):

Have your connection string look something like this:

```
Data Source=foo.secureserver.net; Initial Catalog=DB_123456; User ID=someuserid; Password=somePassword;
```

All the values are specific to what GoDaddy has supplied you. Your Control Panel must have this information somewhere.

Comment: my data source is this: ourweddingevent.db.7048906.hostedresource.com what should be the data source then, please do keep in mind i said LIKE goDaddy my client is not using GoDaddy.

Comment: Also i want to connect this DB using Management Studio as well as .NET